# compare date and give the highest date in a separate field

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I wanted to compare the 4th and 14th date field from my file and identify the greatest date and append it as the last field of the file.the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format, if the dates are same then pick one date. how can i achieve it in unix, any suggestions/help..thanks in advance unix community

input:

```
BMW,X5,bmw.x5@email.com,2016-07-02,0,0,NY,id_1,data1,90909,0,1990-03-18,2015-11-12,2016-09-05
AUDI,A5,audi.a5@gmail.com,2018-08-27,1,1,AZ,id_2,data2,80909,0,1989-04-23,2015,10-21,2018-06-13
```

outputshould be

```
BMW,X5,bmw.x5@email.com,2016-07-02,0,0,NY,id_1,data1,90909,0,1990-03-18,2015-11-12,2016-09-05,2016-09-05
AUDI,A5,audi.a5@gmail.com,2018-08-27,1,1,AZ,id_2,data2,80909,0,1989-04-23,2015,10-21,2018-06-13,2018-08-27
```

Comment: Please add your efforts in your post which you have put to solve the problem.

Comment: i was doing some trial and error method with epoch function in unix.

Comment: It is always good to add your efforts as we all are here for learning, kindly do so.

Comment: this is a eye opener for me. i never thought it is this small, i did some reasearch on internet and started using epoch function to my script. thanks for your expertise, i appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$(NF+1)=$4>$NF?$4:$NF} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: excellent soln! i appreciate it. one question, where are you comparing the 12th field here

Comment: Can i know where the comparison between 4th and 12th field is happening here?

Comment: @mac_online, `$NF` means last field, represents here.

Comment: awesome. i wanted to compare 2nd and 12th field also, 12th field also was date, i accidentially missed it while copying.. i did something like this awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$(NF+1)=$4>$12?$4:$12} 1' and it's working

Comment: @mac_online, cool you could select field number as per your choice here, no issues in it.

Comment: thank you Ravinder! your answer showed me a new path for more recovery in Unix. thank you Stackoverflow and wonderful unix experts!! god bless you